# Problems getting title of windowsapps, such as Photos

Tags: windows, winapi, microsoft-metro

I have a need to get the handle of the window showing a particular image so that it can be aligned with other windows. ShellExecuteEx is used to launch the registered application for the image type, and this works OK (even when the registered application is a DLL, as in the case of 'Photo Viewer').

Unfortunately, the new windowsapps under Windows 10 (e.g. 'Photos' aka "microsoft.photos.exe") don't seem to be playing fair. AssocQueryString says no application is associated with the image type if I had manually associated 'Photos', even though 'Photos' is launched OK when I double-click on such an image.

The title bar for the 'Photos' window clearly says something like 'Photos - file.jpg', but calls to GetWindowText only returns the "Photos" part, with no identifying filename. I also tried sending a WM_GETTEXT message to the window but the result was the same.

Is there something odd about these windowsapps? What is the rationale for only returning the generic part of the window title? Is there a way to get the whole window titles, as displayed?

Comment: The window title is "Photos" (as you can see in taskbar tooltip or ALT-TAB list of windows). The "Photos - blah.jpeg" text is internal/unreliable and just drawn. If you want inner details, you must use UI automation. For example use the inspect tool from SDK and you will see more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects anything you see with that tool you have a programmatic access.

Comment: You never explained what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier. I hadn't noticed that it wasn't a real window title. I was so used to seeing the filename identified in the real title bar of other image viewers.

Comment: @IInspectable, the question does say that I'm trying to get the handle of the window showing the image. I was using the title bar to distinguish one window from another in all other cases.

Comment: The question is essentially explaining your proposed solution. It doesn't explain or even hint towards what the *problem* is. That's known as the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**the question does say that I'm trying to get the handle of the window showing the image. I was using the title bar to distinguish one window from another in all other cases.**

It has been pointed out in the comments that you need to use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-uiautomationoverview) to reliably obtain the title text.

You can try the following code to get the control title.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <UIAutomation.h>

IUIAutomation* pClientUIA;
IUIAutomationElement* pRootElement;

void FindControl(const long controlType)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    BSTR name;
    IUIAutomationCondition* pCondition;
    VARIANT varProp;
    varProp.vt = VT_I4;
    varProp.uintVal = controlType;
    hr = pClientUIA->CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_ControlTypePropertyId, varProp, &pCondition);
    if (S_OK != hr)
    {
        printf("CreatePropertyCondition error: %d\n", GetLastError());
    }

    IUIAutomationElementArray* pElementFound;
    hr = pRootElement->FindAll(TreeScope_Subtree, pCondition, &pElementFound);
    if (S_OK != hr)
    {
        printf("CreatePropertyCondition error: %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
    IUIAutomationElement* pElement;
    hr = pElementFound->GetElement(0, &pElement);
    if (S_OK != hr)
    {
       printf("CreatePropertyCondition error: %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
    hr = pElement->get_CurrentName(&name);
    if (S_OK != hr)
    {
       printf("CreatePropertyCondition error: %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
    wprintf(L"Control Name: %s\n", name);
}

int main()
{

    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINITBASE_MULTITHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
    if (S_OK != hr)
    {
        printf("CoInitializeEx error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }



    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CUIAutomation, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IUIAutomation, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pClientUIA));
    if (S_OK != hr)
    {
        printf("CoCreateInstance error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    HWND hwnd = (HWND)0x00030AF6;  //hwnd of "Photos"
    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        printf("FindWindow error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    hr = pClientUIA->ElementFromHandle(hwnd, &pRootElement);
    if (S_OK != hr)
    {
        printf("ElementFromHandle error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    FindControl(UIA_TextControlTypeId);
}
```

Debug:

[image]